# Integer to binary without multiplication or division

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having trouble with writing a python program that reads an integer number and displays its binary representation, WITHOUT MULTIPLICATION OR DIVISION?
So it's supposed to convert like the integer 5 into 101.. Anyone can help out? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can calculate `bin` like this:

```
def bin2(x):
    binary_digits = []

    while x:
        binary_digits.append(x & 1)
        x >>= 1

    return "".join(str(digit) for digit in reversed(binary_digits))
```

Comment: Wow, it works! Thanks alot! May I ask, what does this do x >>= 1? and the binary_digits.append(x & 1)? Thanks :)

Comment: @Apple. `x & 1` masks out the least significant bit of `x`. `x >>= 1` shifts all bits right by one. Combine these two in a loop until we've had all bits and you read out all the bits one by one, only in reverse order. That's why we reverse the digits before returning them in the last line.

Comment: So for example, given an integer x = 5, when it reaches binary_digits.append(x & 1), what actually happens? And when it reaches x >>= 1, what happens?

Answer (score 6):

```
print(bin(5))   # yes, it's this easy
```

Comment: `bin(5)[2:]` might be more along the lines of what OP wants (to exclude the pesky leading `0b`)

Comment: There's no need to code it by hand, it's built into Python. If you wanted to code it by hand, any sane way would certainly use either multiplication or division.

Comment: Binary shifts are faster than multiplication or division, so they would actually be the correct way to implement this if you had to, let's say, for homework... :).

Comment: But binary shifts *are* multiplication and division.